# Send trigger email when someone connects to a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

How do I set up a trigger or alert so that when anyone connects to a specific database, an email will get send with that user's login credentials?

Comment: Do you want the username only or the username *and* password?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? A [**Logon trigger**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) is what you are looking for.